# EntityFramework update existing records with new foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database and a set of tables that already have data in.
I am using code first. Now I have been asked to add a **Category** table to the database and with that, to change some of the other tables to reference that table via a foreign key.
I know through previous experience, that if I update the database after changing the models, it will moan because an FK can't have 0.
So I want to use the **Seed** method to actually update the Foreign Keys as the database is updated.

I want to do something like this:

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
{

    // Create our categories
    context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id,
        new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Cameras" },
        new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Televisions" }
    );

    // Get all our current feeds
    var feeds = context.Feeds.ToList();
    context.Feeds.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id, feeds.Select(m => m.CategoryId = 1).ToArray());
}
```

Can someone let me know how I might actually do this? Or if there is another way of doing it?

Comment: context.Feeds.ForEach(f => f.CategoryId = 1);

Comment: @SteveGreene, `Foreach` is a method of `List<T>`, it would be  
`context.Feeds.ToList().ForEach(f => f.CategoryId = 1);`

Comment: you can have a null FK as well, if you don't actually need a CategoryId on everything. Null is valid for a FK if you allow it in the design of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a loop:

```
foreach(var f in context.Feeds)
{
   f.CategoryId=1;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or using [Entity Framework Extended library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended) to do it in one batch:

```
context.Feeds.Update(f=>new Feed{CategoryId=1});
```